# Inconsistency in model diagnostics multinomial regression

Tags: regression, ordinal-data

I am using ordinal regression (parallel) on a total dataset of 15706 points, for 10 categories, and testing whether additional predictors significantly improve the model fit. 
I started with 2 predictors, obtained a deviance of 16530 and plotted expected vs observed counts: [image: Counts - 2 predictors]

Then I added a 3rd predictor (which I logically believe should help improve the fit), obtained a deviance of 15241, also compared this model with the first one (2 predictors) using the likelihood ratio test and found that the more complex model fits the data better. 
However, when I plotted the counts for this case, it looks worse than the fit using 2 predictors. 
[image: Counts - 3 predictors]

What could be possible reasons for this?

For information, I am using matlab and counting unique combinations of predictors for each response category, which means I will actually have more points in the case with 3 predictors (including more points with only one instance). I cannot see why this would be a problem but this might affect the results in a way I am not aware of.